# Need help in retrieving MySQL data from a WAMP installation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Here's my situation: I decided to reinstall WAMP so I had to back up my databases, 50+ of them. Then I went on and did it. Then I started importing the databases back to phpMyAdmin, but got only 17 databases. Turns out phpMyAdmin never backed up any more. Now I have WAMP version 2.2 installed, with MySQL version 5.5.24, which is the only one in the WAMP menu. BUT, I do still have the old MySQL version 5.1.36 in my wamp/bin/mysql folder - with all the data files and so forth.

**How can I either**

get the data from 5.1.36 (I doubt just copy-pasting would work)

-- or --

get MySQL 5.1.36 back in my WAMP menu?

Comment: if you have older folder, you can copy paste folders and check. I guess it would work. Not sure though, you should give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded MySQL 5.1.36 from WAMPServer homepage as an addon and installed it (backed up the original). This way I got 5.1.36 back in the WAMP menu and now I have my data back, yay!